# SQL: Compare Date Range in a String text field

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, compare, date-range

I have an MS Access db. I am writing an application in C# to access it. I have a field "`FileName`" of type "`Short Text` in MS Access. Data in FileName field is like "`Test 11-12-2004 15.11.15`".

Using a Date Range, I got to search records based on FileName field. I am not able to get - How do I compare the date of this format and retrieve the records ? FileName is a Text type and date is a substring of it. Retrieving only the date part and comparing with `>= beginDate && <= endDate` seems like a puzzle to me.

Can anyone suggest how do I write SQL query to perform this date range comparision and retrieve those records - "Select * from TestHead where FileName......" ????

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: I would add a new column `FileDate` Date/Time type to the table and filled this column based on file name. It can be done once using cycling thru records in C#. After this you'll be able to do high speed search using regular SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your C# code, as you are going through the records, I'd split the string like this:

```
char[] delimiters = {' '};
string[] FileNameParts = FileName.Split(delimiters);
```

This will result in an array `FileNameParts`, the second element of which will contain the date, which you can convert to an actual date for use in the query:

```
DateTime FileNameDate = Convert.ToDateTime(FileNameParts(1))
```

Something along the lines of:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE " & beginDate & " <= " & FileNameDate
```

I see this as preferable to adding a column to your table that contains the date substring of the FileName field, because then you constantly need to be updating that column whenever existing records are modified or new records are added. That means more clutter on the C# side, or an `UPDATE` query on the Access side which at least needs to get called periodically. Either way it would be more communication with the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, updating the new column value will be more problematic. This dis help me. Instead of Convert.ToDateTeime, I had to use DateTime.TryParseExact - as convert was using different format than beginDate & endDate. Yet, to make sure I set the same format for all 3 date events; resulting in no mismatch at all. Thanks a lot.